# Return an ArrayList of GameObjects and grid issue

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I was trying to generate a grid Unity3d and store all the tiles in an array. I want to use the created array also in others function.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class createGridClean : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject tilePrefab = null;
    public int numberOfTiles = 10;
    public int tilesPerColumn = 4;
    public float distanceBetweenTiles = 2.0f;
    public Material newmat = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        CreateTiles ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public ArrayList[] CreateTiles(){
        GameObject[] allTiles = new GameObject[numberOfTiles*tilesPerColumn];
        float xOffset = 0.0f;
        float zOffset = 0.0f;
        for (int createdTiles = 0; createdTiles <= numberOfTiles; createdTiles++) {
            xOffset += distanceBetweenTiles;
            if ( createdTiles % tilesPerColumn == 0){
                zOffset += distanceBetweenTiles;
                xOffset = 0.0f;
            }
            allTiles[createdTiles] = Instantiate (tilePrefab, new Vector3 (0f + xOffset, 0f, 0f + zOffset), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
        return allTiles;
    }
}
```

But here's the output:

```
Assets/my/Script/createGridClean.cs(34,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to `System.Collections.ArrayList[]'
```

I have have even a problem with the grid, everytime an additional and unwanted extra cube were generated!

(here the original code that I've translated in C#)

```
function CreateTiles()
{
    var xOffset: float = 0.0;
    var zOffset: float = 0.0;

    for(var tilesCreated: int = 0; tilesCreated < numberOfTiles; tilesCreated += 1)
    {
        xOffset += distanceBetweenTiles;

        if(tilesCreated % tilesPerRow == 0)
        {
            zOffset += distanceBetweenTiles;
            xOffset = 0;
        }

        Instantiate(tilePrefab, Vector3(transform.position.x + xOffset, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + zOffset), transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Any help will be fantastic!

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: As is pretty clear from the compiler error your method signature returns an `ArrayList[]` (an array of ArrayLists??), but your trying to return `GameObject[]`. Change your method signature to match the type you are actually trying to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
public ArrayList[] CreateTiles()
{
    GameObject[] allTiles = new GameObject[numberOfTiles*tilesPerColumn];
...
    return allTiles;
}
```

to:

```
public GameObject[] CreateTiles()
{
    GameObject[] allTiles = new GameObject[numberOfTiles*tilesPerColumn];
...
    return allTiles;
}
```

The error message you're getting: `Cannot implicitly convert type X to Y` refers to the fact that you're implicitly converting your `GameObject[]` to an `ArrayList[]`.  You must either explicitly cast to an `ArrayList[]` (e.g. `return (ArrayList[]) allTiles`, although I'm not sure that's what you're after), or change your method to return a `GameObject[]`.

Your question is a duplicate of all these other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+implicitly+convert

Comment: Wow LordScree, I search here for a couple of hours without finding nothing. Your answer was really helpful. Sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to have helped. Next time you get an error try searching for parts of the message (in this case: _cannot implicitly convert_).